# Node WebKit and YouTube: chrome is not defined

Tags: javascript, youtube, gruntjs, node-webkit

I'm developing an app for `Android`, `iOS`, `Mac OS` and `Windows` using `PhoneGap` and `Node-WebKit`. This application has embedded `youtube` videos.

These `youtube` videos are working fine in my `Mobile` app (`Android`/`iPhone`) using `PhoneGap`, but if I test it on my `Mac` (building the app using [`grunt node-webkit builder`](https://github.com/mllrsohn/grunt-node-webkit-builder)) I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: chrome is not defined
>   www-embed-player.js:184

I tried to check that line and there is some code like:

```
chrome.cast.requestSession(v(this.Lc,this)
```

I'm embedding the videos using an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rjKRQYmi1Lk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" ></iframe>
```

Anybody knows how can I solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Same happened to me today. Still can't resolve this issue.

Comment: It happens for me on Android phones... Maybe a core YouTube bug?

Comment: I have opened an issue on the node-webkit github page https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/2291

Comment: Ok, the error is probably not connected to the issue that the videos don't play, as adding `"user-agent": " Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405",` in `package.json` removes all errors, but the video still shows the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is related to the Chromecast Chrome plugin. I'm assuming you have

```
"webkit": {
    "plugin": true
}
```

in your manifest for flash, so the Chromecast plugin is also getting loaded. Then when it tries to interact with the YouTube player it fails.

Try removing the Chromecast plugin to see if this resolves the issue. if so then your options are:

1. Remove the Chromecast plugin, there isn't a way to only load specific plugins in node-webkit that I'm aware of. This may not be the best solution especially if you are distributing your app.
2. Use another method to load the YouTube video. I use the JavaScript Player API and I don't have any issues. You can find my example here:

   https://gist.github.com/octalmage/03a054bb27d597a9f095

   And the API reference:

   https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Embedding
3. Load your HTML over a local webserver. This error seems to be caused by using the file:// protocol so loading your HTML using a local webserver might resolve the issue. I personally use this with method 2 to get past the restricted playback errors (https://cloudup.com/cUXiDgrYBOm) but I'm not sure if it will fix your issue alone.

Edit: I just realized I get this error with webkit plugin set to false, try setting it to true! The video works for me without any changes when webkit plugin is enabled. The error does flash before the video plays though.

https://cloudup.com/c6VyHbIyyez

Comment: Hi, I just set the webkit plugin to true and now the video is playing! As you said, it still shows the error before playing, but this is enough while we consider using the JavaScript Player API. Thank you!