# Embedding Youtube videos not working with Node-webkit

Tags: youtube, embed, node-webkit, nw.js

I have an embedded youtube video in my nw.js app. The preview for the correct video shows up properly but when I click to play it I am met with the following error:

[An error occurred, please try again later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqliG.png)

All of the videos in the app get this error, except for one that gets this puzzling error:

[The following video contains content from the International Basketball Federation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1azf.png)

When I click these videos, I can see the first split second of the video before the error shows up.

I tried enabling/disabling the webkit plugin in the manifest:

```
  "webkit": {
    "plugin": true
    }
```

and I tried using the Javascript Player API as suggested by in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622310/node-webkit-and-youtube-chrome-is-not-defined). However I still get the same errors.

How can I get these videos to play properly?

Here is the HTML (I'm using angularJS and the video is in a modal window) that displays the video:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <object width="100%" height="600px" data={{video}}> 
        </object>

</script>
```

I also tried copying [this example](https://gist.github.com/octalmage/03a054bb27d597a9f095) using the Javascript Player API and even tried using the same video as the example but I'm still getting the same error.

Thank you very much for your time. Let me know if you need anything else from me or if I am being unclear.

Comment: Could you provide a jsbin?  Here's one based on the example that is working: http://jsbin.com/dupubebego/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: For some reason that js.bin isn't displaying the first video (the one using the player api) in the output for me. [Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nJK64aPyzbXeISC8KEAb?p=preview) working properly displaying both videos. I'm trying this exact same code in a nw.js app and receiving the errors described above for the iframe video, and no display at all for the other video.

Comment: Thanks! Well, I can reproduce it working Chrome (on Win 7) and reproduce it NOT working exactly like you described in Internet Explorer 10. Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the issue was the ffmpegsumo.dll. At first I tried replacing it with the dll from chrome 39 and 42 and that did not fix my issue. After replacing the file with the ffmpegsumo.dll from Chrome 38.0.2125.122, my issue was fixed and videos played as expected.

[Chrome 38.0.2125.122 ffmpegsumo.dll 32 bit](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=80546501735641471695)

[Chrome 38.0.2125.122 ffmpegsumo.dll 64 bit](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=98439818087699648975)

Comment: where to place this ffmpegsumo.dll file? Does we need to inject it somewhere in node-webkit ?

Comment: @KamaldeepSingh just replace the ffmpegsumo file that exists in the root folder of your application. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/6LDj0zv.png) is a photo of one of mine.

Answer (score 0):

You need the flash plugins in the `plugins` directory at the same root level as the `package.json` `NPSWF32_13_0_0_214.dll`and `NPSWF32_14_0_0_125.dll`. This with the above will enable Flash.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! Know where I can download these files? After googling, I found [npswf32.dll](http://opendll.org/index.php?file-download=npswf32.dll&arch=32bit&version=9.0.28.0&dsc=#) but adding that did not change my problem. Can you please direct me to a download of those two specific dll's you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in Linux 64 bits using Yeoman Node Webkit Generator (https://github.com/Dica-Developer/generator-node-webkit/wiki/Getting-Started)

Just fixed it by adding the so lib:

```
$ cp nwjs/nwjs-v0.12.0-linux-x64/libffmpegsumo.so  dist/Linux64_v0.12.0/
```