# Where to find ffmpegsumo libraries for nw.js 0.12.0? (Play audio files in Nodewebkit)

Tags: audio, dll, chromium, nw.js

Hello I am working in an application using NW.js 0.12.0 (nodewebkit) and I need to find the ffmpegsumo.dll file of Google Chrome 41.0.2272.76 in order to be able to play audio files. See: [NW.js Docs About it](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Using-MP3-&-MP4-%28H.264%29-using-the--video--&--audio--tags.)

Also I found this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29078623/4779735) and the 32 bit works, but the 64 does not work for me.

Where can I find?

- ffmpegsumo.dll (Win 32 bits)  [FOUND HERE!](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=80546501735641471695)
- ffmpegsumo.dll (Win 64)
- ffmpegsumo.so (Mac OX)
- ffmpegsumo.so (Linux)

I know that someone else will need this as well so I will update this and add links as soon I find the files!

Answer (score 2):

Found a working [ffmpegsumo.dll](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=01677383619096417495) for the Win 64 v0.12.1 of Node Webkit. This dll is from chrome version 42.0.2311.135.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in the `soundnode` app project (Soundcloud desktop app, unofficial), available on Github [here](https://github.com/Soundnode/soundnode-app)

Just navigate to [assets/codecs-libs/](https://github.com/Soundnode/soundnode-app/tree/master/assets/codecs-libs) and there are the 64bit/32bit up-to-date libraries for Linux/Mac at least.

The [win32 dll](https://github.com/Soundnode/soundnode-app/tree/master/cache/0.12.3/win32), as well as all the libs, by platform, can be found in [cache/](https://github.com/Soundnode/soundnode-app/tree/master/cache/0.12.3) folder.

While the [MacOS 64 .so](https://github.com/Soundnode/soundnode-app/tree/master/cache/0.12.3/osx64/nwjs.app/Contents/Frameworks/nwjs%20Framework.framework/Libraries) library is part of the nwjs distribution.

Answer (score 0):

[Get ffmpegsumo.so (Linux)](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=09944566854548956912) from Chromium 41.0.2272.118 (tried, works)

Comment: You can build ffmpegsumo and nw.js easily, i made this a day ago, look at end of thread https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1461

Answer (score 0):

Every ffmpeg library could support different video formats depending on compilation options, I think your best option could be "popcorn time" or compile it yourself, popcorn time build using node webkit just download the official app for the OS you need and you can go to the installation directory and you will find the library there, in OSX case you can find it inside the app of course.

github project: https://github.com/popcorn-official/popcorn-desktop

application page: https://popcorntime.sh/

Answer (score 0):

0.12.3 32bit OSX here, for some reason the only that worked was the one posted at the end of this thread: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/2256 it's a link to google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-W5PD832un2ZGJLc3R6SFZwc1k&authuser=0