# Replacing the ffmpegsumo in nwjs makes the application crash

Tags: dll, chromium, node-webkit, nw.js

I'm working on an application using NW.js 0.12.3 (node-webkit) where I need to use a correct version of ffmpegsumo in order to have it work. In my chrome folder I couldn't find it.

So I tried the one mentioned in: [Where to find ffmpegsumo libraries for nw.js 0.12.0? (Play audio files in Nodewebkit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590898/) but that didn't worked.

What I did is replacing the ffmpegsumo in the folder where NW is installed, but when I run my app it crashes the moment it wants to play the mp3 song. I also couldn't find any log of the crash. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Windows 8.1 and NW.js stable version (0.12.3). [The most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30101172/1812182) by user brspnnng in the link you provide takes you to download a dll that worked for me (so far).